# Finding Favorites I haven't shared

Tags: photos.app

In Photos.app, I have the special Favorites smart album and an iCloud Shared Album called Shared Favorites. I display Shared Favorites as our AppleTV screen saver. The issue is that when I favorite a photo, I have no easy way to reliably add it to the Shared Favorites album.

I was hoping to create a smart album containing photos that are a favorite and are not in Shared Favorites. But iCloud Shared Albums are not listed as albums.

When I tried dragging all of the Favorites into the Shared Favorites album, I wound up getting hundreds of duplicates.

Any ideas for a workflow that lets me just add new favorites to a shared album?

Comment: I looked at the AppleScript dictionary, but it doesn't expose iCloud Shared Albums as scriptable objects. I'm not sure this is possible at the moment.

Comment: It seems absurd, but my current best strategy is, every month, to delete every photo from Shared Favorites, then drag over all images from Favorites. Hopefully, Apple will address this in a future update.